# How do I remove some numbers in a string in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a generated string and I want to remove some of its contents.

example: &H1B, &H00, &H10, &H23, &H03, &HBE, &H00, &H08, &H01, &H02

I want it to be: &H1B, &H0, &H10, &H23, &H3, &HBE, &H0, &H8, &H1, &H2

How can I do it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use String.Replace.

```
theString = theString.Replace("&H0", "&H")
```